# Can I change the default folder location for applications?

Tags: sql-server

Basically I want to know if it is possible to change the path of certain applications that are saving folders in My Documents. For example:

Whenever I open SQL Server Management Studio it creates a folder in my documents with the path:

```
D:\Documents and Settings\ptr1yzj\My Documents\SQL Server Management Studio
```

Basically what I want to do is move this folder to another folder, lets call it Programs. Thus the path would be:

```
D:\Documents and Settings\ptr1yzj\My Documents\Programs\SQL Server Management Studio
```

The reason for this is I am kind of OCD with my files and folders and would like to clean up my documents as much as possible.

Comment: This is program-dependent. That is, there is no single, universal setting you can change (and how could there be for the specific example above?) Instead, you have to do a [file](https://www.google.com/search?q=search+file+contents) and registry (`regedit`) search for the path (in your case you would want to search for `ptr1yzj`) and then change it (if possible) to point to the new one. For example, with Firefox, you have to edit the `profile.ini` file to point to the new path.

Comment: @Synetech Yeah, I was poking around in the regedit for several applications, but I couldn't really find anything that worked sadly.

Comment: Did you do a (binary) file-search?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this specific tool. If it allows you to change the default folder, I expect that the help file will tell you. If not, try contacting their support team.

There might, however, be an alternative that at least goes part way to solving your issue.

When using NTFS formatted drives, you can make use of links just like you can with Linux and other Unix-like OS's.

So you could move everything to the folder you want, delete the folder you don't want and then create a link from the wanted folder to the old folder name.

The unwanted folder still appears in folder listings but, in Windows Explorer, it will have the link logo overlayed on the folder icon. So not quite ideal but you will be able to make changes to files in either location without worries.

You can create links from the command line using the `mklink` command. Personally, I use an Explorer add-in called "[Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)".

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on versions... and whether express/standard versions, but you can check here:

the key is:
DefaultFileOpenLocation

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\Shell\General\ProjectLocationEntries

OR

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Shell

OR

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ShellSEM

you also might have to change several keys... so look around some in those areas at the paths.

Comment: I looked all over, everyone I changed it still somehow creates the file.